# How to build a sauna?

Tags: outdoor, studs, construction, planning

I would build my own DIY sauna, but I can't seem to find extensive information about it. Nor I can find plans to build one. How can I build one?

My father has a lot of home building knowledge, but we've never built a sauna.

Comment: I have built a few of them in kit form, they are pretty basic. Cedar finish, cedar slated benches heat and steam source. The info is out there, I will see what I can find

Comment: I just Googled "sauna plans" there is a boatload of them out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built a few of them in kit form, they are pretty basic. Cedar finish, cedar slated benches heat and steam source. The info is out there.

This is a [website](https://1859oregonmagazine.com/live/home-garden/outdoor-sauna/) for free plans so it says. Looks like it has a lot of info on it.

Comment: Site is now a spam site. Might have been legit at one time, but it's just a squatter now.

Comment: I will edit the answer